Get connected and disconnected device from thingsbaord
I need some ideas about how we can get connected and disconnected devices in optimized ways from thingsboard. For example, I have 50,000 or maybe more from the thingsboard. I know there is a Server_Scope where we can check every device's active (true or false) state. But I was thinking of fetching all the devices and then calling the telemetry API from thingsboard one by one to get the Server_Scope for each device. But this will slow down the process. I was thinking of some solutions like

Create a scheduler to store the number in Redis, and then the user can call the endpoint to get it from Redis. The scheduler will run every hour to update the values in the Redis.
Something from the rule chain the get the connect and disconnect event.

I need to implement it in typescript. Although I have already written the code to first fetch all the devices and call telemetry API to get Server_SCOPE it returns the data, but kind of very slow. As it hits like 500000 calls to the telemetry.
Any ideas to optimize it in a better way
